# Client Credential call for OAuth 2.0 providing "unsupported_grant_type"

Tags: salesforce1-app, oauth2, api-client-certificate, client-id

> **{"error": "unsupported_grant_type","error_description": "grant type not supported"}**

I am creating a app to connect Salesforce to communicate(app-myApp to app-salesforceApp). 
So we took the channel "Client Credential" to communicate, I refer the blogs and documents provided over the internet, but not able to make the postman call based on that, but I was able to make the call for "ROPC:Grant type-password", "Authorization code: Grant type-authorization_code", but when I am trying to connect with the "Client Credential" than I am getting the above error.
Below is the cURL request to connect:

```
curl "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=<CALLBACK_URI>" -X POST
```

Even same, request I tested in the Postman agent but getting the same issue.
Could you tell me that what I am making wrong here or does the Salesforce support the Client Credential?

Answer (score 1):

Client Credentials grant type is [not supported](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm) by Salesforce. Recommended (and better) alternative for app-to-app calls is [JWT Bearer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5).